# Space Character in XML doc gets converted to funky ? char in SQL Server and on web page

Tags: sql-server, xml, character

This is a snippet of text from the source xml document:

> Great Lakes. The largest

It looks like there is a normal space between the period after Lakes and the word The after the period.  But this is what it turns into in Sql Server.

> Great Lakes.�The largest

I assume I need to replace the unknown character with a regular space character in our import tool (a c# console app) prior to loading the file as a proper `XmlDocument`.  We're already doing stuff like that:

```
_buf = _buf.Replace("\x1E", "");
_buf = _buf.Replace("\x1C", "");
```

The person who wrote that isn't here anymore and I don't have much experience with character issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replacing on that question mark character seems to have fixed the problem.

```
_buf = _buf.Replace("�", " ");
```

It may be a naive approach, but there are no more funky chars on the web page so I'm going with it for now.